# How to dynamically calculate mean of Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, math, mean, series

I have a Series that contains some keys and values, just like:

```py
> first
x    0.167965
y    0.380518
z    0.443677
dtype: float64
```

And from time to time, I'll have another one, same structure but different numbers, like:

```py
> second
x    0.242322
y    0.991292
z    0.850728
dtype: float64
```

I want to get their mean. For that, I can create a DataFrame, add them as rows, and grab the mean:

```py
> df = pd.DataFrame()
> df = both.append(first, ignore_index=True)
> df = both.append(second, ignore_index=True)
> df
          x         y         z
0  0.167965  0.380518  0.443677
1  0.242322  0.991292  0.850728
> first_second_mean = both.mean()
> first_second_mean
x    0.205144
y    0.685905
z    0.647203
dtype: float64
```

And that's cool, it works and all.

Another thing I can do is add them directly, and then divide:

```py
> added = first + second
> added
x    0.410287
y    1.371810
z    1.294405
dtype: float64
> first_second_mean = added / 2
> first_second_mean
x    0.205144
y    0.685905
z    0.647203
dtype: float64
```

If there's a third one, I can scale it up:

```py
> third
x    0.252872
y    0.791024
z    0.809272
dtype: float64
```

If I do the DataFrame approach with all three:

```py
> df = pd.DataFrame()
> df = df.append(first, ignore_index=True)
> df = df.append(second, ignore_index=True)
> df = df.append(third, ignore_index=True)
> df
          x         y         z
0  0.167965  0.380518  0.443677
1  0.242322  0.991292  0.850728
2  0.252872  0.791024  0.809272
> df.mean()
x    0.221053
y    0.720945
z    0.701226
dtype: float64
```

And if I manually add and divide:

```py
> added = first + second + third
> added
x    0.663159
y    2.162834
z    2.103677
dtype: float64
> added / 3
x    0.221053
y    0.720945
z    0.701226
dtype: float64
```

And that works, but I have to keep track of every single one of the Series, and what I need is a way to do it with only the previous average, something like this:

```py
> df = pd.DataFrame()
> df = df.append(first_second_mean, ignore_index=True)
> df = df.append(third, ignore_index=True)
> df
          x         y         z
0  0.205144  0.685905  0.647203
1  0.252872  0.791024  0.809272
> df.mean()
x    0.229008
y    0.738464
z    0.728237
dtype: float64
```

And, well, the results don't match up. If I try the manual adding and dividing approach:

```py
> added = first_second_mean + third
> added
x    0.458016
y    1.476929
z    1.456474
dtype: float64
> added / 2
x    0.229008
y    0.738464
z    0.728237
dtype: float64
```

---

**Correct mean of all three:**

```py
x    0.221053
y    0.720945
z    0.701226
dtype: float64
```

**Incorrect mean of all three:**

```py
x    0.229008
y    0.738464
z    0.728237
dtype: float64
```

So obviously, my math is wrong. How can I, using only the previous mean (`first_second_mean`) and the new Series (`third`) calculate the correct mean, as if I had calculated the mean of all the parts (`first`, `second` and `third`) directly?

I want to keep only the mean, and update it with any new values as they come, and this might happen a lot of times, not just three, as in this example.

Comment: `(first_second_mean * 2 + third)  /  3`?

Comment: @ScootCork thanks. For exactly 3 items that does the trick. For *n* items, I believe the answer by Elliott Collins might be the best way to go about it. I think both are basically the same thing mathematically, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update an average, you have to keep track of how many you've averaged over so far.

Assuming you've got one series `avg`, which is the average over `N` previous items and a new item `new`, then just do

```
avg = (N*avg + new)/(N+1)
N += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is very clear and easy to understand. I was hoping there'd be some wizardry that'd bend math and make it possible to not keep a counter, but that doesn't seem to be how math works.

Answer (score 0):

Do small sef_def function

```
def ave_sum(l):
    prev = l[0]
    for cur in l[1:]:
        prev = (cur + prev)/2
    return prev
ave_sum([f,s,t])
Out[242]: 
x    0.229008
y    0.738464
z    0.728237
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question was a bit confusing, I'll try to edit it a bit. The last two results I got were the "wrong" mean, and the first four, the "desired" ones. I believe my phrasing in the question has mislead you, and I'm sorry for that. Your solution still faces the problem of my last few examples, as it miscalculates the mean of all those values.